# Using lists to get average

Tags: python, list, average

This program is supposed to ask the user for monthly rainfall input for 12 months, calculate and total the rainfall for the year, the average monthly rainfall and the months with highest and lowest amounts.

I can get it to ask for input, give  yearly total and average monthly, but I feel as though the input portion of the program should be  cut down somehow,, it looks too big and bulky, and I can't quite figure out how to get the high/low average.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```
def main():
    jan = int(input('Enter Rainfall For January: '))
    feb = int(input('Enter Rainfall for February: '))
    mar = int(input('Enter Rainfall For March: '))
    april = int(input('Enter Rainfall For April: '))
    may = int(input('Enter Rainfall For May: '))
    june = int(input('Enter Rainfall For June: '))
    jul = int(input('Enter Rainfall For July: '))
    aug = int(input('Enter Rainfall For August: '))
    sept = int(input('Enter Rainfall For September: '))
    oct = int(input('Enter Rainfall For October: '))
    nov = int(input('Enter Rainfall For November: '))
    dec = int(input('Enter Rainfall For Deceember: '))
    totalyear = jan + feb + mar + april + may + june + jul + aug + sept + oct + nov + dec
    print('The total for the year is: ',totalyear)
    avg = jan + feb + mar + april + may + june + jul + aug + sept + oct + nov + dec / 12
    print('The average monthly rainfall is: ',avg)
main()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a list and a loop. :)

```
def main():
    months = ["Jan","Feb" .... ,"Dec"]
    rain = []
    for month in months:
        rain.append(int(input("Enter .. for" + month)))
    print("Total", sum(rain))
    print("Average", sum(rain)/float(len(rain)))
```

Similarly, for maximum and minimum you can use `max(rain)`, and `min(rain)`.